# What are the appropriate pulse width and PRF for a pulsed Doppler sensor

Tags: rf, signal-processing, pulse, sampling

I have a raw k-band transceiver, radar-based 24 GHz, motion detector, IPM-165.

and here is the datasheet:
https://www.innosent.de/fileadmin/media/dokumente/DATASHEETS_2016/Datenblatt_IPM-165_V8.5.pdf

I want to design an amplifier with a **50 kHz bandwidth**. I want also to run the device in a pulse mode to save power. Probably 20% of duty cycle is fine to save fifth of the consumption.

I have two parameters which I should design.

1) the pulse width.
2) the pulse repetition frequency (PRF).

and I know the sampling frequency should be 2*50 kHz at minimum according to Shanon.

So what are the calculations of these two parameters in order to sample & reconstruct a signal of 50 kHz at maximum?

Answer (score 0):

You must define your required range and velocity specs with CNR/SNR where this ratio determines FSK improvement on noise reduction which requires maybe 1000x the BW limited by minimal detection threshold of Shannon’s Law which would be unusable.

Typical application is a time linear cycle (FMCW) or step ramp up in f of delta F ranging from 100MHZ to 1GHz depending on your specs.

Fundamentals : https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&ei=TsuAXbPwMIvatAXvgruQAg&q=24GHz+Doppler+module+modulation&oq=24GHz+Doppler+module+modulation&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3...3337.7315..7807...0.1..0.121.1058.8j3......0....1.........0i71j0i22i30j33i22i29i30j33i160j33i21.rONhGjEifpQ

Comment: I only want to measure the velocity, the range does not matter. The datasheet says the radio has around 11db SNR. I have no idea how to calculate CNR.

Comment: You need to learn how FMCW works